# Replace elements of a list by elements of other list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

Consider the following Python list of lists:

```
my_list = [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6, 2], [7, 6, 4, 3], [8, 6, 3], [9], [10, 4, 3], [11], [12, 9], [13, 11, 12]]
```

Every element of `my_list` is a list starting with its index in `my_list` and the other values are less than the first one, and so also appears as 1st element of some previous list.

For example, `my_list[8]`  is `[8, 6, 3]` (and everybody knows that `6,3 < 8`).

I'd like to do the following replacement when is possible: if `s` in `my_list` contains an element `s_i` such that some previous element `r` in `my_list` is as `[s_i, a, b, c]` (or longer), replace `s_i` in `s` by `s_i, a, b, c` (or more).

For example, instead of `[13, 11, 12]` ***(could be done for other elements too)*** in `my_list` I'd like to get `[13, 11, 12, 9]` since `[12, 9]` is in `my_list` also.

But, notice that this procedure should be done recursively, if necessary.

For example, suppose that `[9, 4]` is in `my_list`, then the result should be `[13, 11, 12, 9, 4]`.

Or, since `[6, 2]` is in `my_list`, such replacement should be done also for `[7, 6, 4, 3]` and `[8, 6, 3]`.

Sorry, if is not clear what I need. I think that defining some function and call it in `while` could be a profit.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7, 6, 4, 3], [8, 6, 3], [9], [10, 4, 3], [11], [12, 9], [13, 11, 12]]

def by_first(l):
    d = {}
    for i in l:
        if len(i) > 1:
            d.setdefault(i[0], []).append(i)
    return d

index = by_first(my_list)

def dfs(item):
    for p in index.get(item[-1], []):
        q = item + p[1:]
        yield q
        for v in dfs(q):
            yield v

for l in my_list:
    for p in dfs(l):
        print p
```

The index contains:

```
{7: [[7, 6, 4, 3]], 
 8: [[8, 6, 3]], 
 9: [[9, 4]], 
 10: [[10, 4, 3]], 
 12: [[12, 9]], 
 13: [[13, 11, 12]]}
```

Prints without `[9, 4]`:

```
[13, 11, 12, 9]
```

If we add `[9, 4]`:

```
[9, 4]
[12, 9, 4]
[13, 11, 12, 9]
[13, 11, 12, 9, 4]
```

These are the items that had at least one other item appended to them. `[9, 4]` is there because it is appended to `[9]`

It appears that you might only want the longest.

To get one of the lists with the same number of items as the longest only do the following:

```
def find():
    for l in my_list:
        #yield l
        for p in dfs(l):
            yield p

print max(find(), key=len)
```

If you want the initial lists to be included uncomment the line `yield l`.

Comment: Amazing!! And you are right, I will use only the last one: `[13, 11, 12, 9, 4]`.

Comment: What is `yield`?

Comment: I'd like to update `my_list` (or create a new one) replacing the elements by those computed as above. I think I can do this. Let me try.

Comment: I edited and added `[6, 2]` to list. The replacement should work also for `6`.